# login box design

Tags: css

jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DoyleRaymond/G3VgY/1/).

In this example, I just want to overlap "JOIN US" link border and login box border so that when the user clicks the "JOIN US" link, the login box appear and it'll look like in one box.

I set:

```
border-bottom : white
```

in "JOIN US" link but it didn't overlap and display as I want. one things, I can't delete "z-index" because there are necessary to me.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/G3VgY/8/)?

Comment: but in my project, there are many div that have to use z-index so when i set z-index to "-1", login box hides under the other slider div.. do u have any other advice ?? @JCOC611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a rounded edge, theres a CSS property cal `border-radius`. Just use `element_id/class/name:hover { border-radius: 10px; }` and you'll be done. I recommend you have a look at the new CSS3 tags and features.

Comment: thanks for round edge, @Ayush Khemka. i just want to look like a box when user click "JOIN US" link..

Comment: if u're done, pls upvote and accept the answer you feel is correct. this would help others too. (and me too btw :P)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `border` tag for your .nav1 class, use two separate `border-top` and `border-bottom` or use shorthand, but do not use the `border-right` or `border-left` property. Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DoyleRaymond/G3VgY/1/)

Comment: i also want a round edge rectangle when user hovers on that element. so you have any other options you can give advice??